# How can I make applications in a specific directory not to be associated with file types in OSX?

Tags: macos

I got a few software that I don't really need them to be associated with file types, so I put them in a directory other than the standard locations like "/Applications" or "~/Applications", but somehow the system still was able to dig them out and add them into the "open with" list in the context menu.
My question is how can I force the system to just ignore them, thus keep my open with list compact.

Comment: Also, OS X is smart like that. `/Applications` is in no way special, the system tracks everything on the disk. **Maybe** putting them in a directory not indexed by Spotlight would work since that might be what's used under the hood.

Comment: Nope, it's not the Spotlight who does the trick, because I have turned the indexing service off completely since the first day I got my mac. I'm not a fan of it.

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong OS ;) Aaanyway, the [Launch Services documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABEJFCD) has the following to say: "The Finder automatically registers all applications as it becomes aware of them, such as when they are dragged onto the user’s disk or when the user navigates to a folder containing them." The only available API seems to be for **registering** an application, not unregistering it.

Comment: Somewhat unsurprisingly, OS X seems to favour consistency here instead of developer (or power user) control. As a lateral suggestion: poke around a Finder replacement like Path Finder? Maybe a power-user-oriented Finder alternative will let you customise its own context menus if not the systemwide one.

Comment: Thank you for your replying, I figured a workaround may actually work in this case, which is deleting all type association entries in **Info.plist** file in the app bundle, but for tens of apps, it seems a lot of work to do if I don't implement it in a programming way. Maybe I'll code a python tool and give it a try. BTW, I tried pathfinder, it didn't work neither(without Finder running).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the workaround. It worked.

```
import plistlib
import os
import sys
import shutil

SUBDIR_PATH=os.path.sep.join(('Contents', 'Info.plist'))

class FileTypeCleaner(object):

    def __init__(self,pathOfFile):
        self.filepath = self.checkInfoPlistExistence(pathOfFile)
        if self.filepath is not None:
            try:
                self.plistdata = plistlib.readPlist(self.filepath)
            except:
                self.plistdata = None
        else:
            self.plistdata = None

    @staticmethod
    def checkInfoPlistExistence(pathOfFile):
        path=os.path.sep.join((pathOfFile, SUBDIR_PATH))
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            return path
        return None

    def checkInfoPlistHasTypeKey(self):
        if 'CFBundleDocumentTypes' not in self.plistdata or \
                self.plistdata['CFBundleDocumentTypes'] == []:
            return False
        return True

    def vacuumTypeKey(self):
        self.plistdata['CFBundleDocumentTypes'] = []


if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)==1:
        sys.stderr.write('Usage: cleanFTypeAssoc.py app1.app [app2.app ...]\n')
        sys.stderr.flush()
        raise SystemExit
    for f in sys.argv[1:]:
        p = FileTypeCleaner(f)
        if p.plistdata is not None:
            if p.checkInfoPlistHasTypeKey():
                p.vacuumTypeKey()
                shutil.move(p.filepath, p.filepath+'~')
                plistlib.writePlist(p.plistdata, p.filepath)
```